# What's the difference between polyurethane finish and polyurethane plastic?

Tags: polymers

The **plastic version** is made by mixing two liquid chemicals (MDI & polyol) which react immediately and become a solid. **Polyurethane finish** is applied as a liquid and dries, no mixing involved.

- Or are they not related at all?

Prompted by [Veritasium YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWkYRh6OXy8).

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too.